# « Code golf » : de quoi aurait l'air l'emprunt hybride ?

Tags: anglais, syntaxe, formulation-idiomatique, emprunts, morphologie

Le « [code golf](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_golf) » est une forme de compétition de « programmation récréative durant laquelle chaque participant s'efforce d'implémenter un algorithme donné en produisant un programme le plus court possible » (Wikipédia ; un [site](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) du réseau y est consacré).

Si on essaye d'[hybrider](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=4063) l'emprunt intégral (*[code golf](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/code_golf)*) en employant une syntaxe/morphologie française, quel mot détermine-t-il l'autre et comment relie-t-on les deux (en anglais *code* précède *golf* et il n'y a rien entre les deux ; il s'agit de l'analogie avec le *golf*) et incidemment comment formulerait-on typiquement une phrase avec ça ; avec quel verbe (semi-auxiliaire  typique) l'emploierait-on ?

---

"*Code golf* is a type of recreational computer programming competition in which participants strive to achieve the shortest possible source code that implements a certain algorithm" ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_golf)).

The loanword *Code golf* is used as is in French but if you try to [partially adapt](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=4063) its morphology or syntax to French, then what about word order and how would you connect those words together (in English you seemingly have *code* modifying *golf* and that's it) and incidentally how would you typically phrase that i.e. which (typical semi-auxiliary) verb would you use with that?

---

Voir aussi/See also:
[« Code golf », l'emprunt intégral : précisions sur l'emploi ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/39546/19187)
[« Code golf » : le choix de l'analogie dans la traduction ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/39517/19187)

Answer (score 2):

Une compétition de code minimum pourrait s’appeler ***Mini Code***, en résonance avec
une *[mini-jupe](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minijupe)* qui se porte elle aussi à la ceinture, précurseur de la *[mode mini](https://www.universalis.fr/encyclopedie/mode-mini/)*, mode qui peut aussi envahir les styles de programmation et devenir  ***Code Mini***.

Alors que le dessin du pantalon de golf est normalisé, on pourrait entendre durant les rencontres au sujet de l'algorithme en compétition :

> On va lui tailler une minijupe sur mesure