# « Code golf » : le choix de l'analogie dans la traduction ?

Tags: traduction, informatique, formulation-idiomatique, néologismes, sport

Le « [code golf](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_golf) » est une forme de compétition de « programmation récréative durant laquelle chaque participant s'efforce d'implémenter un algorithme donné en produisant un programme le plus court possible » (Wikipédia ; un [site](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) du réseau y est consacré).

Y a-t-il déjà eu des suggestions de traduction et avec un néologisme, le sport, le nom [*golf*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/golf#Fran%C3%A7ais) évoquent le mieux/le plus typiquement ce dont il est question et autrement quel autre sport ou quoi d'autre dans la tradition linguistique du français évoquerait le *plus petit nombre de coups* etc. et pourrait nous servir dans ce cas ?

---

"[Code golf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_golf) is a type of recreational computer programming competition in which participants strive to achieve the shortest possible source code that implements a certain algorithm" (Wikipedia; a [site](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) is dedicated to this on the network).

Were there ever any proposed translations for this and with creating a new word from scratch here is *sports* and "golf" the topic that most typically comes to mind here? What other sports or what else from the French linguistic tradition would be most reminiscent of what is *the shortest* or *achieved with as few shots as possible* and would work in context?

---

Voir aussi/See also:
[« Code golf », l'emprunt intégral : précisions sur l'emploi ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/39546/19187)
[« Code golf » : de quoi aurait l'air l'emprunt hybride ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/39515/19187)

Comment: C'est le genre de terme qui est généralement utilisé tel quel, sans traduction. La traduction est-elle utile (dans quel contexte) ou juste un exercice intellectuel ?

Comment: D'accord avec le commentaire de @MathieuBouville dans la mesure où ce *code golf* me rappelle dans sa formation la *partie blitz* que l'on joue toujours aux échecs sans jamais l'avoir modifié.

Comment: Si la question porte sur l'existence d'une traduction "officielle", pas à ma connaissance. Sinon la question risque probablement d'être insolvable et les réponses subjectives...
Quant aux sports pouvant convoyer un sens similaire je pense à la pétanque, aux fléchettes, tir au but,... D'autres activités pourraient être plus appropriées pour une "bonne" traduction.

Comment: Le contexte c'est toujours celui de voir comment on s'y prend pour s'exprimer sur un éventail de sujets. J'ai rédigé une question sur l'emprunt intégral si on s'y s'intéresse. Ici, on peut songer à comment on aurait mis au point le terme si on l'avait imaginé dans un contexte francophone et quelles références font davantage l'unanimité et comparer avec une autre langue, comme l'anglais. On peut vouloir disserter du sujet et l'expliquer à des non initiés, à des enfants, à des aînés. On se demande si on a déjà exploré certaines pistes et non si on a statué en terminologie...

Comment: Le but est de faire le score le plus bas : en nombre de caractères (_code golf_) ou de coups (golf). Donc un principe différent des exemples de @Kii.

Comment: Le terme `factorisation de code` est parfois substitué à `code golf`, ce qui est un tort car ils ne sont pas équivalents

Answer (score 3):

Deux idées :

1. En rapprochant Code Golf d'un type de composition écrite dans un style laconique (concis), cela donnerait :

Code Laconique / Programme Laconique

Laconique en référence aux Lacédémoniens habitants de Lacédémone / Laconie et leur façon de s'exprimer.

Exemple du CNTRL pour l'entrée lacédémonien:

*Vous écrivez avec une concision toute lacédémonienne et, de plus, vous avez un papier qui sans doute ne se fabrique qu'exprès pour vous (Mérimée, Lettres à une inconnue, t. 2, 1860, p. 138)*

Deux possibilités existantes quand on les google. L'idée du plus court possible n'est pas peut-être pas assez présente avec cet adjectif laconique. C'est un début.
En jouant un peu sur les mots, on obtient :

***LaCODique***

[Lacédémonien / laconique](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/lac%C3%A9d%C3%A9monien)

2. Vous pouvez aussi essayer de regarder si les membres de l'OULIPO (ouvroir de littérature potentielle) n'ont pas essayé de formuler une contrainte équivalente (utiliser le moins de mots possible) pour définir un terme, écrire un texte.
   Dans le code golf, un premier programme proposé dans un langage donné peut se voir raccourci par les autres codeurs ou son auteur.  Un peu dans l'esprit des idées du *fondu* ou de l'*Haï-kaïsation* de l'OULIPO de faire de plus en plus court.

Une idée à connotation un peu trop poétique d'inspiration OULIPO-japonaise :

***Haï-Codaïsation***

[Une liste des contraintes oulipiennes](https://www.oulipo.net/fr/une-liste-de-contraintes-oulipiennes)