# « Code golf », l'emprunt intégral : précisions sur l'emploi ?

Tags: prononciation, verbes, orthographe, formulation-idiomatique, emprunts

Le « [code golf](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_golf) » est une forme de compétition de « programmation récréative durant laquelle chaque participant s'efforce d'implémenter un algorithme donné en produisant un programme le plus court possible » (Wikipédia).

On a l'emploi en [*emprunt intégral*](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?Th=2&t1=&id=3787) « code golf ».

- Typiquement en français métropolitain, prononce-t-on l'un ou l'autre
  ou les deux mots comme en anglais (/koʊd/ /gɒlf/gɔlf/) ?
- Dans la documentation ou dans la communication formelle, est-ce entre
  guillemets, en italiques et y a-t-il majuscule initiale avec le
  premier ou les deux éléments du mot à la fois ?
- Est-ce une compétition à laquelle on *participe*, un tournoi auquel on *prend part*, est-ce que l'on s'y *adonne* ou y *joue*-t-on comme au golf, peut-on *faire un/du code golf*, : pourquoi un verbe serait-il
  préférable à un autre pour signifier ce que fait une personne dans ce
  contexte ; pense-t-on plutôt à faire de l'emprunt un verbe ?

---

"*Code golf* is a type of recreational computer programming competition in which participants strive to achieve the shortest possible source code that implements a certain algorithm" ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_golf)).

The [loanword](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?Th=2&t1=&id=3787) *Code golf* is used as is in French.

- Typically in Metropolitan French, will either or both of these words
  be pronounced like in English (/koʊd/ /gɒlf/gɔlf/)?
- With documents and formal communication, is that used with quotation
  marks, italics, do you have the initial uppercase letter with either
  or both words?
- Is it some type of contest where you *compete*, do you *take part* in
  what amounts to a tournament, do you *play* it, can you *do* code golf, can you do *a* code golf: why
  would you prefer a verb over another to reflect what a person is
  doing in this context; would one rather think of using it as a verb instead?

---

Voir aussi/See also:
[« Code golf » : le choix de l'analogie dans la traduction ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/39517/19187)
[« Code golf » : de quoi aurait l'air l'emprunt hybride ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/39515/19187)

Answer (score 3):

Typiquement en Français métropolitain, quand un mot est aussi proche du mot français on le prononce à la française. "Golf" est déjà rentré dans la langue et "code" a exactement le même sens qu'en français, donc à mon sens il est naturel de prononcer les deux mots à la française.

De la même manière, pour le film "Source Code" dont le nom a été gardé tel quel, je n'ai rencontré personne qui ne prononce pas les deux mots à la française. Un titre comme "Danger Zone" serait différent ("danger" prononcé à l'anglaise et "zone" soit à la française, soit éventuellement /zoʊn/ selon la personne)

Je pense que c'est un mot trop récent pour qu'on puisse répondre à ta deuxième question. Beaucoup trop subjectif.

Intuitivement je dirais "faire du code golf", il n'y a pas nécessairement de compétition (on peut en faire seul chez soi).